# Sequelize does not include attributes (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

i am trying to create select with "custom" attribute.
Everything is working fine except that the "custom" attribute is not included.
Query is generated correctly so it should work but...\

Sequelize: 6.19.0
MySQL2: "^2.3.3"

DB options:

```js
import { Options } from 'sequelize'

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const development = {
    url: process.env.MYSQL_URL,
    options: {
        minifyAliases: true,
        logging: false,
        pool: {
            max: 4
        },
        dialect: "mysql",
        dialectOptions: {
            dateStrings: true,
            typeCast: true,
            timezone: "+02:00",
            multipleStatements: false
        },
        timezone: '+02:00'
    }
}
```

Select:

```js
    const currentPrices: any = await CurrentPrice.findAll({
        limit: 10,
        logging: true,
        attributes: {
            include:
            [
                [Sequelize.col("date"), "test"]
            ]
        },
        where:
            filter
    })
```

Generated query:

```sql
SELECT `item_id`, `city`, `sell_price_min`, `sell_price_max`, `buy_price_min`, `buy_price_max`, `date`, `date` AS `_0` 
    FROM `today_price` AS `currentPrice` 
    WHERE `currentPrice`.`date` >= CURRENT_TIME - interval 1 hour LIMIT 10;
```

Output:

```json
{
    "currentPrices": [
        {
            "item_id": "T4_CLOTH",
            "city": "Bridgewatch",
            "sell_price_min": 159,
            "sell_price_max": 178,
            "buy_price_min": 152,
            "buy_price_max": 157,
            "date": "2022-05-07 17:35:02"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
    "currentPrices": [
        {
            "item_id": "T4_CLOTH",
            "city": "Bridgewatch",
            "sell_price_min": 159,
            "sell_price_max": 178,
            "buy_price_min": 152,
            "buy_price_max": 157,
            "date": "2022-05-07 17:35:02"
            "test": "2022-05-07 17:35:02"
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT//**

So i tried add "raw: true" to my findall.
The result contained "attribute include" but attribute name were "_0" instead of "test"
Still trying to find solution.

**EDIT//**

Its started to work when i turned off "minifyAliases" as Anatoly wrote.

Comment: What options did you indicate in Sequelize itself?

Comment: Options added to the post.

Comment: Did you try to indicate a name other than `test`?

Comment: I tried anything even some random letters

Comment: Turn off `minifyAliases`